# ng-options not displaying or linking objects

Tags: angularjs

I have three entities: `Project`, `Customer` and `Reference`
A `Project` has two selection fields: `Customer` and `Reference`.
In the `Customer` object there are multiple `References`.
Therefore a `Reference` is only available for selection when a `Customer` with `References` is selected.

**My problem**: I only either get the `Reference` selection to work, or the initial `Customer` loading, not both.

On loading a `Project` with this the `Customer` is showed properly in the select field:

```
<select id="customer" ng-model="selectedProject.customer"
        ng-options="customer.id as customer.name for customer in customers | orderBy:'name'">
    <option value="">keine Angabe</option>
</select>
```

But no `References` are shown, even though the selected `Customer` has some.

```
<select id="reference" ng-model="selectedProject.reference"
        ng-options="reference.name for reference in selectedProject.customer.references track by reference.id">
    <option value="">keine Angabe</option>
</select>
```

If I change the `Customer` selection to this, the `References` are shown, but the `Customer` selection field is empty when loading a `Project`:

```
<select id="customer" ng-model="selectedProject.customer"
        ng-options="customer.name for customer in customers | orderBy:'name' track by customer.id">
    <option value="">keine Angabe</option>
</select>Project
```

How do I get both working?

> EDIT
>   I got both working by doing this:

```
ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers | orderBy:'name'"
```

And overwriting the id with the object on `Project` selection:

```
$scope.selectedProject.customer = $scope.getCustomer($scope.selectedProject.customer);
```

But now a new problem occurs, I can't save the project anymore as it expects a reference, not the customer object.

Comment: `selectedProject.customer` is the value of `customer.id`. An ID doesn't have references. Read the docuentation of ng-options. If you want `selectedProject.customer` to be a customer, and not an ID, the syntax is `ng-options="customer as customer.name for ..."`

Comment: For a customer to be pre-selected with this syntax, `selectedProject.customer` must be `===` to one of the customers in the array of customers.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I changed `customer.id as` to `customer as`, not working. Because it is not `===`? Then how do I make it `===`? Or is there a better solution, like retrieving the customer object in the reference selection from the id?

Comment: two references are === when the refer to the exact same object. So, find the customer, inside the array, that you want to pre-select, and store **that** customer into `selectedProject.customer`.

Comment: @JBNizet too late for that, I would have to change every Project in the DB then I assume(?)

Comment: No. Why would you have to do that? You have an array of customers you display as options. You want one of the options to be pre-selected. So `selectedProject.customer`should be that customer object. i.e. for example, if you want the third customer of the array to be preselected, you should have `$scope.selectedProject.customer = $scope.customers[2];`. Your database is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet but I want the `Customer` that the `Project` has in the DB to be preselected

Comment: @JBNizet I guess something like `$scope.selectedProject.customer = $scope.customers[$scope.selectedProject.customer];`

Comment: No. $scope.selectedProject.customer is an object. Not the index of an array. Find the one in the array that has the same ID.

Comment: @JBNizet I checked what `{{selectedProject.customer}}` prints, it prints an id - so I think the name is misleading and caused some confusion. But I still can't find a solution - the [workaround](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/) with the extra property did not work for me

Comment: If you haven't changed anything to your code, of course it prints an ID. That's what I've been telling you from the start. If you have done what I suggested to fix your issue, and still have problems, then post what you have tried, and tell what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet thx, I got it working but of course once two things works a third breaks xD